# Smooth animation not working when on the same page as target element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have a navigation where one of the li is an anchor link to a solution overview on the root page ("Home"). I use this js to scroll to the element if I am on another page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    if (window.location.hash) {
        //setTimeout(function() {
            //$('html, body').scrollTop(65).show();
            $('html, body').scrollTop(0);
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top - 65
                }, 2000);
        //}, 0);

        console.log('Yes');             

    }       
});
```

It works fine if I am on another page ... but If I'm on the root page the animation does not work. Why?

Navigation:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="domain/">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="domain/company">Company</a></li>
      <li><a class="scroll-to" href="domain/#solution1/" target="_top">Solution 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="domain/team/">Team</a></li>
      <li><a href="domain/location/">Location</a></li>      
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Anchor element on root:

```
<div id="solution1"></div>
```

Update: When putting it in a function it also not doesn't work. The redirection and scrolling works ... but not the animation if I am on the same page as the element:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function scrollAnchor() {
    if (window.location.hash) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            //$('html, body').scrollTop(65).show();
            $('html, body').scrollTop(0);
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top - 65
                }, 2000);
        }, 0);          
    }
}

scrollAnchor(); 

$('.scroll-to').on('click', function() {
    scrollAnchor();
});
```

Comment: When is the function being called if you're already on the page? Wrap it in a named function and call it on anchor click.

Comment: Unfortunately did not help. Now the animation when coming from another page does not work. I updated above. What else could it be?

Comment: Oh ... and I load the script on every page ... and when I'm already on the same page as the element to scroll to ... then the animation is not working ...

Comment: You need to call the function onload and onclick.

Comment: I don't get it. It's working when the page loads with scrollAnchor(); and coming from another page ... but still not when on the same page ... how exactly should I do the onclick? Like above?